# construct nonvanishing one form on $\mathbb{RP}^3$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I met such a problem in my homework: construct an everywhere nonvanishing 1-form on $\mathbb{RP}^3$; can your construction be generalized to $\mathbb{RP}^n$?

I know nothing about the background of the exercise and have no idea how to deal with such a problem (I'm a beginner on manifolds and know very little about algebraic topology). I guess the concrete construction may push out some 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you construct a nonvanishing one form on $S^3$?  And perhaps another hint:  a manifold admits a non-vanishing 1-form iff it admits a non-vanishing vector field.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh, is it $xdy-ydx+zdt-tdz$? so I can push out this via the projection?

Comment: You can push it down to $\mathbb{R}P^3$ iff it is invariant under the antipodal map.  So is it?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, thanks! So I can use this as a general construction for $\mathbb{RP}^n$ when n is odd. But is there any similar construction for the even case? I guess when $n$ is even the answer is negative, but the nonexistence may require some topology?

Comment: @JasonDeVito By the way, is this a theorem? [ iff it's invariant under the antipodal map] I can think of it as a covering space, and I find the conclusion quite natural. But I didn't see it on any text.

Comment: There is no non-vanishing $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$, but the only proofs I know require some topology.  Namely, a non-vanishing $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ pulls back to one on $S^{2n}$.  From the fact that the tangent and cotangent bundles of any manifold are isomorphic, this turns into a non-vanishing vector field on $S^{2n}$.  But these don't exist, from the Hairy Ball Theorem.

Comment: @JasonDeVito thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know of any text that has the result I mentioned, but it's not too hard to prove.  Given any form on a manifold $X$ with universal covering $\overline{X}$, you can pull back the form and verify that it's invariant under the deck group.  Conversely, if a form on $\overline{X}$ is invariant under the deck group, you define a form on $X$ as follows.  For $p\in X$, pick a neighborhood $U$ for which the projection trivializes.  Then we get many smooth maps $U\rightarrow \overline{X}$ (one for each sheet in the cover) by inverting the projection map on $U$....

Comment: Now, pull back the form on $\overline{X}$ via any one of these maps.  The fact the form on $\overline{X}$ is invariant under the deck group means your definition of the form on $X$ is independent of which of the maps $U\rightarrow \overline{X}$ you pick, so you get a well defined smooth form on $X$ (which pulls back to the form you started with on $\overline{X}$).  By the way, please feel free to write up an answer to this problem yourself.  I don't need the reputation points :)

Comment: @JasonDeVito thank you so much, and I'll feel guilty of not upvoting! :) I took this result for granted before. Now I understand my understanding wasn't very rigorous before.

Comment: @JasonDeVito You should turn all those comments into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As observed in the comments, we have the following proposition:

**Proposition**:  Suppose $\pi:\overline{X}\rightarrow X$ is a normal covering map of smooth manifolds ("normal" in the sense that $\pi_\ast(\pi_1(\overline{X}))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$).  Then a $k$-form $\overline{\omega}$ on $\overline{X}$ is of the form $\pi^\ast \omega$ for a $k$-form $\omega $ on $X$ if and only if $\overline{\omega}$ is invariant under the group of deck transformations.

**Proof**.  First, assume $\overline{\omega} = \pi^\ast \omega$ for some $k$-form $\omega$ on $X$.  Let $f$ be any deck group transformation, meaning that $\pi = \pi\circ f$.  Then \begin{align*} f^\ast\overline{\omega} &= f^\ast (\pi^\ast\omega)\\ &= (\pi \circ f)^\ast \omega\\&= \pi^\ast\omega\\&=\overline{\omega}.\end{align*}  Thus, $\overline{\omega}$ is invariant under the action of the deck group.  (The proof we just completed doesn't require a normal covering - any covering is ok.)

On the other hand, now assume that $\overline{\omega}$ is invariant under the deck group.  We define $\omega$ on $X$ as follows.  Pick $x\in X$ and let $U\subseteq X$ denote any evenly covered neighborhood of $x$, meaning that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of $U_\alpha$ where $\pi$ maps each $U_\alpha$ to $U$ diffeomorphically.  I will let $\pi_{\alpha}$ denote the restriction of $\pi$ to $U_\alpha$.  Then each $\pi_{\alpha}$ is a diffeomorphism from $U_\alpha$ to $U$.

Picking any single one of the $U_\alpha$ (which I'll call $U_0$), we define $\omega$ on $U$ by $\omega = (\pi_0^{-1})^\ast \overline{\omega}$.

What happens if we pick a different $U_\alpha$, say $U_1$?  Well, because $\pi$ is a normal covering, there is a deck group element $f$ which maps $U_0$ to $U_1$.  Then, $ \pi_0 = \pi_1\circ f$.  Thus, because $\overline{\omega}$ is invariant under the deck group action, we see that \begin{align*} \omega &= (\pi_0^{-1})^\ast \overline{\omega}\\ &= (f^{-1}\circ \pi_1^{-1})^\ast \overline{\omega} \\ &= (\pi_1^{-1})^\ast(f^{-1})^\ast \overline{\omega}\\ &= (\pi_1^{-1})^\ast \overline{\omega}.   \end{align*}   So, the definition of $\omega$ is independent of which $U_\alpha$ we pick.  In a similar fashion (with ommitted calculation), $\omega$ is also independent of the choice of trivializing neighborhood.

To conclude the proof, we need only demonstrate that $\pi^\ast \omega = \overline{\omega}$.  To see this, note that any $\overline{x}\in \overline{X}$ lies in some open set $U_0$ which is mapped diffeomorphically to an open set $U$ in $X$.  Then $\pi = \pi_0$ on $U_0$, so $\pi^\ast(\omega(\pi(\overline{x}))) = \pi_0^\ast( \pi_0^{-1})^\ast \overline{\omega} = \overline{\omega}$.  $\square$

Armed with this, to find a non-vanishing form on $\mathbb{R}P^3$, you can instead find a form on $S^3$ which is preserved by the antipodal map. As you wrote, the form $ydx - xdy + zdt - t dz$ does the trick (interpreting $(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{R}^4$).  And, as you noted, this generalizes to any odd dimensional $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

As mentioned in the comments, the even dimensional $\mathbb{R}P^n$s do *not* have a non-vanishing $1$-form on them, as a consequence of the Hairy Ball theorem for $S^{n}$.

Comment: The nonexistence of nonvanishing 1-form also follow from Poincare-Hopf theorem: if exist such 1-form then $1=\chi(\Bbb RP^{2n})=\sum_{x\in zero}\rm  Ind (x)=0$ is a contradiction.